# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: java, android

I know there are other questions on SO asking the same thing. I have already looked at most of them.

Most answers call about memory errors. But I think I have already check it.
Here is mu logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.batteryalarm/a.batteryalarm.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                    at a.batteryalarm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5082)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_error.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005e
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1936)
                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3345)
                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:142)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                    at a.batteryalarm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5082) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:891)
                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:828)
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1933)
                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3345) 
                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:142) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080) 
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                    at a.batteryalarm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5082) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

All of my **imageView**s are almost the same:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/health_ok"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_check" />
```

**ic_check.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#79d71c"
    android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z"/>
```

(MainActivity.java:46): `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Will appreciate any help or hint. Thanks in advance

Comment: `ResourceNotFound: File res/drawable/ic_error.xml` @ `line #65: Error inflating class ImageView`... So do you have `@drawable/ic_error` there?

Comment: @cricket_007, yeap, I have it there. And everything works fine on Android 5.0 or higher, but under 5.0 - I have such mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone, who was trying to help me. Finally I solved my problem using this scheme:

[image: include a vector drawable into project]